# css overflow-x: hidden ----> hide y axis overflowed ( i did overflow-y : visible )

Tags: css

First of all, I'm sorry of my *ugly english* OTL.

[image: no problem with .main-content]

[image: no problem with .main-content > .inner]

[image: no problem with .main-content > .inner > .single-post__title.]

until, no problem , .single-post__title is hided by main-content. because .main-content is overflow:hidden ! x axis and y axis all!

But, I want to see .single-post__title so then I change .main-content 's overflow:hidden to ->>> overflow-x: hidden & overflow-y: visible.

And this is result....

[image]

Why ? , And what I should do to show .single-post__title ???

---Update 01
add jsfiddle -> 
https://jsfiddle.net/MR_RPF/zayewjjq/

```
.container {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
.inner {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 30px;
}
.title {
  background: pink;
  margin-top: -36px;
  height: 40px;
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="title">
      HELLOW WORLD
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

--update 02
What I want to see view is this.
[image]

Comment: Can you please create fiddle with your code

Comment: https://codepen.io/YOONBYEONGIN/pen/KmdqXW

Comment: That code is incomplete

Comment: What do you want ??

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/MR_RPF/zayewjjq/   here

Comment: @SahilDhir are you asking me?

Comment: @Sai No !! I am asking [RPF] , the  question is not clear at all

Comment: (Thank you for all comment : )   )  I want to see .single-post__title with overflow-x : hidden & overflow-y: visible.   overflow-x is needed some reason.

Comment: @RPF Try to create fiddle with similar kind of problem you wrote in the question. The fiddle which you created is not matching with the question.

Comment: Your question is still not  clear.

Comment: http://magaziner.simpli.co.kr/this-is-gallery-post-format/   here is my page,, as you can see , the .main-content > .inner > .single-post__title is not shown! even if I change the .main-content's overflow:hidden to overflow-x: hidden & overflow-y : visible,,, try please

Comment: and In jsfiddle , .container 's < overflow-x : hidden & overflow-y: visible > is not work as I expected ( I think .title should be shown in overflow-y: visible ! )

Comment: Where do you want to show the title text ?

Comment: on picture , so When I apply no overflow propery to .main-content ( .single-post__title is  < margin-top : -150px; > )  ,, then all works around, but when I apply overflow:hidden to .main-content , the .single-post__title is hidden , and when I apply < overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: visible > to .main-content, .single-post__title not shown OTL...

Comment: really thanks all people : )

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xMddf/2/  this is what I want to but , not works in my case ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try bellow CSS

```
.single .main-content {
    margin-top: -272px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    overflow-y: visible;
}
.main-content .inner {
    margin-top: 184px;
    background: #fff;
}
.single-post__title {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: -138px;
    color: white;
}
```

I've modified css in console check the Screenshot below

[image]

Comment: But, still it's mysterious the way of overflow-x , overflow-y be working (english ugly OTL).

Comment: Overflow visible means it will show the content out of box also, but here the problem not fully with overflow property but also margin which you have given

Answer (score 1):

In this case the class `single_post_title` is culprit. Don't set the color to white and set height and margin properly.

```
.single-post__title {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height: 47px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @RPF is this what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: Thank you , but it's not what I want. Now I want to understand why < overflow-x : hidden 
 > hide  < overflow-y: visible >

Answer (score 0):

Try to add position relative in .main-content

```
.single .main-content{
  position:relative;
}
```

Then in .single-post__title add position absolute.

```
.single-post__title{
  position:absolute; 
}
```

Hope it Works

Comment: thanks for your answer! but , I don't want to use absolute property